# Appending a string to a two dimensional array of char?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C, and I have the following question, if I have an two dimensional array of `char`, and a lone string:

```
char strings[4][6] = {"hello", "Hi", "bye"};
char lonestring[6] = "lone";
```

I want to add this string to the two dimensional array so it becomes: {"hello", "Hi", "bye", "lone"}

```
char strings[3] = lonestring;
```

But when using the following code if I get an error, what's going wrong?

Comment: You cannot **add** to a 2D array in C. You can use a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* or a *pointer-to-array-of-char* and dynamically allocate to accomplish the addition.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Forgive me as I'm new to the language, but would you be willing to provide an explanation of what you mean?

Comment: You can declare a *pointer to pointer to char* (e.g. `char **strings;`) and then allocate the number of pointers you need (e..g `strings = malloc (nstrings * sizeof *strings);` and then you can allocate storage for each pointer sufficient for the string you want to store (e.g. `strlen ("hello")` is `5`, so you allocate `strings[0] = malloc (6);` and then copy, e.g. (`strcpy (strings[0], "hello");`). (you can then `realloc` more pointers as required). If you have a fixed size `char (*strings)[6];`, you then can use a single allocation `strings = malloc (nstrings * sizeof *strings);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char strings[4] = lonestring;` attempts to define an object named `strings`, yet `char strings[3][5]` already exists.  Thus an error.

To copy the *string* contents of `lonestring` to `strings[3]`, use `strcpy()`.

```
strcpy(strings[3], lonestring);
```

The usual concern applies: Insure the destination is big enough - as in this case.

---

With `char strings[4][5]`, The initialization of `strings[0]` with `"hello"` does not result in a *string* as `strings[0]` lacks a *null character*. [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808157/appending-a-string-to-a-two-dimensional-array-of-char/52808206#comment92534495_52808157).

OP later edited to `char strings[4][6]`.

---

Note: this does not *add* to `strings`, its justs assigned new values to parts of the object.  Once an array is defined in C, its size cannot change.

Simplistically: `{"hello", "Hi", "bye", ""}` became `{"hello", "Hi", "bye", "lone"}`